# Por qué un método retorna x cuando tiene que retornar y?

Tags: java, array, poo, lista, arraylist

Es decir, si le pongo como input en el método `duracionTotalCD`: *el 2do titulo del CD*, me da como output: *la duración de la 2da cancion del 2do CD*, y debería de devolver como output: *la suma de las 2 canciones del 2do CD*.

**NOTA:** El programa no marca ningun error de compilación, simplemente los métodos no regresan lo que tienen que regresar.

```
class CD {

private String titulo, autor;
List<Cancion> listaCanss = new ArrayList<Cancion>();

CD(String titulo, String autor, List<Cancion> listaCans) {
    this.autor = autor;
    this.listaCanss = listaCans;
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

List<Cancion> getlistaCans() {
    return listaCanss;
}

void setlistaCans(List<Cancion> s) {
    listaCanss = s;
}

String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}
class Cancion {

private String titulo;
private double duracion;

Cancion(String titulo, double duracion) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

double getDuracion() {
    return duracion;

}

void setDuracion(double d) {
    duracion = d;
}

public String getTituloC() {
    return titulo;

}

void setTituloC(String d) {
    titulo = d;
}

}

 public class Ejercicio {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<CD> listaCDs = new ArrayList<CD>(3);
    List<Cancion> listaCanss = new ArrayList<Cancion>(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        System.out.println("Nombre CD:");

        String nomCD = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Autor CD:");
        String aut = leer.nextLine();

        leer.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            System.out.println("Nombre cancion:");

            String nomCan = leer.nextLine();

            System.out.println("duracion cancion:");
            double dur = leer.nextInt();
            leer.nextLine();
            listaCanss.add(new Cancion(nomCan, dur));
        }

        listaCDs.add(new CD(nomCD, aut, listaCanss));
    }

    System.out.println("Introduzca el titulo del CD para devolver su 
    duracion total");
    leer.nextLine();
    String stt = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println(duracionTotalCD(stt, listaCDs));

    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre de la cancion a buscar 
    para devolver el CD al que pertenece y su respectivo autor");
    leer.nextLine();
    String st = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println(TitAu(listaCDs, st));


}

static double duracionTotalCD(String titulo, List<CD> listaCDs) {
    double duracionT = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (0 == (listaCDs.get(i).getTitulo()).compareTo(titulo)) {
                duracionT = duracionT + 
  listaCDs.get(i).listaCanss.get(j).getDuracion();

            }
        }
    }
    return duracionT;
}

public static String TitAu(List<CD> c, String n) {
    int tam = c.size();
    String s1 = null, s2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if ((c.get(i).listaCanss.get(j).getTituloC()).compareTo(n) 
 == 0) {
                s1 = c.get(i).getTitulo() + " ";
                s2 = c.get(i).getAutor();
            }
        }
    }
    return s1 + s2;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque estas recorriendo en esa funcion vaya a saber que cosas, pero cuando haces esto:

```
if (0 == (listaCDs.get(i).getTitulo()).compareTo(titulo))
```

te estas fijando si la cancion que buscas es la que pasaste.. no estas haciendo nada con las anteriores...

tu metodo deberia funcionar de otra manera, deberias pasarle el numero de cancion, y en base a eso, sumar la duracion de las canciones hasta esa.

### EDITADO

En base a los comentarios, el problema es otro. Analicemos la funcion duracion del CD.

```
static double duracionTotalCD(String titulo, List<CD> listaCDs) {
    double duracionT = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // 
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (0 == (listaCDs.get(i).getTitulo()).compareTo(titulo)) {
                duracionT = duracionT + 
  listaCDs.get(i).listaCanss.get(j).getDuracion();

            }
        }
    }
    return duracionT;
}
```

Hay dos for en la función, uno itera sobre los cd, el otro itera sobre los temas. Hasta ahí no hay problema... El problema, es que iteran hasta 2. O sea que si hay 4 cds, nunca los vamos a ver. Lo que esta mal es toda la lógica de este método.

Lo que habría que hacer es lo siguiente:

Buscar el cd:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < listaCDs.count; j++) {
     if (0 == (listaCDs.get(j).getTitulo()).compareTo(titulo)) {
```

Una vez que sabemos cual es la j buscada, ahí si recorrer el cd y sumar todos sus temas

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listaCDs.get(i).count ; i++) {

     duracionT = duracionT +   listaCDs.get(j).listaCanss.get(i).getDuracion();
```

### Editado 2:

El pseudo codigo seria:

Iterar sobre los cd buscando cual es el que tenemos que buscar.
Con ese indice
Iterar sobre los temas de ese cd, sumando los tiempos de cada tema.

algo asi como:

```
para cada cd  
{ 
  fijarse si es el cd
    {
      guardar el id del cd  
      salir del for
    }
}   
para cada tema en el cd    
{    
 sumar el tiempo de cada tema    
}
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65061/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-michelle).

Answer (score 0):

`if (0 == (listaCDs.get(i).getTitulo()).compareTo(titulo))`

Esta comprobación debería ir dentro del bucle exterior. En caso afirmativo, recorrerías las canciones, sumando el valor.

De esta forma evitas comprobar en todas las canciones de todos los discos, y solo sumarías en caso que el disco sea el elegido.

Comment: acaso no es lo mismo, es decir, da igual si está en el bucle exterior o interior?